# Multiple error codes using the same schema in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I have a schema for a certain status code that i wan to use in multiple responses.
We can have multiple error messages for the same status code and may be distinct on each response.

`ErrorCode:
      type: object
      properties:
        error_code:
          type: integer
          description: error code
        message: 
          type: string
          example: No Authorization
        description:
          type: string
          example: "You aren't allowed"`

I would like to provide multiple examples for each response.
For example:

`examples:
  1:
    error_code: 1
    message: random 1
    description: description 1
  2:
    error_code: 2
    message: random msg 2
    description: description 2`

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: How can i use the same schema in different responses and provide multiple examples for each and display them for each response?